# Entity Framework - How to Include parent self referencing

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, parent-child, self-reference

Okay - So I have an object called `Employee`.
The employee contains many `HolidayYears` and each of those `HolidayYears` has a one to many relationship with the `Employee`. 
When I try to do the following line of code:

```
public Employee ReadById(int id)
    {
        using (var dbContext = GetContext())
        {
            return dbContext.Employees
                .Include(e => e.HolidayYears.Select(h => h.Employee))
                .Include(e => e.Department)
                .Include(e => e.HolidayYears.Select(h => h.Months.Select(m => m.AbsencesInMonth)))
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        }
    }
```

The first include holds a reference to the parent - "Employee" - and is a self-reference. The HolidayYears loads just fine, but it doesn't include the HolidayYear's employee.

Is there a way to run this, or is self-referencing like this a no-no in the entity framework?

Comment: In short, yes this should work fine, as long as you have defined the relationships correctly in the model self references can be used in EF for sure... You wouldn't have got here if that was wrong. To explain why your results aren't working will need to show us the results of an individual query to get one or many of the HolidayYears with expand on Employee. This looks to be data related. Maybe publish the structure as well.

Comment: [Here is relationship definitions](https://prnt.sc/icbspq) - In theory what I have done should work, but I don't even get a "null" when using postman - I get an Employee with all his holidayyears showing, but none of the holidayyears have the employee property shown. It's not even giving me a null - it's simply put - not there.